# How to change the link text in Drupal 8 Views?

Tags: views, 8

I have a simple problem that I can't seem to resolve despite everything I have tried. Googling for a answer has not turned up anything either. Here is my problem:

I have an entity A that references entity B. What I would like to do is be able to link to entity B's content (by that I mean click a link and be taken to the page the displays entity B's content). In Views you would use the "link to content" switch to accomplish this.

However here is the catch, I would like to use entity A's title as the link's text. I figured this would be an easy thing to do in Views, but no matter what I tried I can't do this.

I have tried rewriting the result in Views, but I can't find a reference to say that you want to link to entity B's url. Using the below substitution:

```
<a href="{{ entityB }}">{{ entityA_title }}</a>
```

you would get a link that looks like:

```
EntityB Title">EntityA Title
```

Where EntityB Title would link to Entity B's content and EntityA Title would link to a page that does not exist. It looks like you can't separate Entity B's title from its url - where I just want its url.

Is there a way to accomplish what I want to achieve? I figure this should be possible and straight forward to do, but apparently not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I do this (just tested it, working):

1. Make sure you have a *relationship* to **Entity B** added to the view.
2. Potential gotcha: Make sure your **Title** *field* for **Entity A** is NOT a link already; you won't be able to use it as a title in a link rewrite if it is already a link.  (If you want to rewrite a title that is already a link, you can add a second title, make the second one not a link, and then use that in your rewrite.)
3. Add a **Path** *field* that uses the **Entity B** *relationship*.  Rewrite it like `<a href="{{ path }}">{{ entityA_title }}</a>`

Comment: Thank-you!!! You don't know how many hours I wasted trying to accomplish this simple task. I never knew there was a Path field that I could use.